# MobileNet ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (24, 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to implement number of networks using Keras applications. Here I am attaching a piece of code and this code works fine for ResNet50 and VGG16 but when it comes to MobileNet it generate the error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (24, 2)

I am working with 224x224 images with 3 channels and batch size of 24 and trying to classify them in 2 classes, so the number 24 mentioned in the error is the batch size but I am not sure about number 2, probably it is number of classes.

Btw is there anyone who knows why I am receiving this error for `keras.applications.mobilenet`?

```
# basic_model = ResNet50()
# basic_model = VGG16()
basic_model = MobileNet()
classes = list(iter(train_generator.class_indices))
basic_model.layers.pop()
for layer in basic_model.layers[:25]:
    layer.trainable = False
last = basic_model.layers[-1].output
temp = Dense(len(classes), activation="softmax")(last)

fineTuned_model = Model(basic_model.input, temp)
fineTuned_model.classes = classes
fineTuned_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
fineTuned_model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=3764 // batch_size,
        epochs=100,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=900 // batch_size)
fineTuned_model.save('mobile_model.h5')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code, we can see that you're popping a `Reshape()` layer. Exactly the one that transforms the convolution's output (4D) into a class tensor (2D).

[Source code:](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/mobilenet.py#L274)

```
if include_top:
    if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        shape = (int(1024 * alpha), 1, 1)
    else:
        shape = (1, 1, int(1024 * alpha))

    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Reshape(shape, name='reshape_1')(x)
    x = Dropout(dropout, name='dropout')(x)
    x = Conv2D(classes, (1, 1),
               padding='same', name='conv_preds')(x)
    x = Activation('softmax', name='act_softmax')(x)
    x = Reshape((classes,), name='reshape_2')(x)
```

But all the keras convolutional models are meant to be used in a different way. If you want your own number of classes, you should create these models with `include_top=False`. This way, the final part of the model (the classes part) will simply not exist and you just add your own layers:

```
basic_model = MobileNet(include_top=False)
for layer in basic_model.layers:
    layers.trainable=False

furtherOutputs = YourOwnLayers()(basic_model.outputs)
```

You should probably try to copy that final part shown in the keras code, changing `classes` with your own number of classes. Or maybe try pop 3 layers from the complete model, the `Reshape`, the `Activation` and the `Conv2D`, replacing them with your own.

Comment: Thanks and there is a short answer also in this link: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/8301